# php openssl asymmetric decrypt

Tags: php, openssl, private-key, encryption-asymmetric

I was hopping someone could help me to understand how to decrypt a xml file that was previously encrypted with a public key. The file is devided into two sections, the **AuthenticatedPublic** section and the **AuthenticatedPrivate** section, inside the latter, there are specific tags like CipherValue, X509Certificate that are suppose to be decrypted with my private key. The steps i have tried were:

1. Parse the entire xml file with **XmlToArray**.
2. Got one of the tags i need to decrypt, which was the cyphervalue.

Then i tried many things like trying to to decrypt using:(i´m using php, so this is inside a function)

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey "'.$privkey.'" -in "'.$tag.'" -out decrypted.xml
```

But the result is an empty decrypted.xml file. I have also tried converting to base64, and then tried to decrypt also, but then i reach an error:

```
rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_pk1.c:273:

5612:error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_eay.c:602:
```

In fact, i´m not really sure if this is the way to decrypt the xml. Any thoughts?

Thanks for your time, Regards

**EDIT**

Has Pak Uula suggested, below is a more detailed information about my xml file, please note that i have hide some of the data for obvious reasons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<DCinemaSecurityMessage xmlns="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-3/2006/ETM" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <AuthenticatedPublic Id="ID_AuthenticatedPublic">
        ...(keys hidded for brevity)
        <RequiredExtensions>
            <KDMRequiredExtensions xmlns="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM">
                ...(keys hidded for brevity)
                ....(below some of the keys that i need to decrypt)
                <CompositionPlaylistId>urn:uuid:d932f6a0-094b-etc-etc-etc</CompositionPlaylistId>
                <ContentTitleText>...</ContentTitleText>
                ..
                <AuthorizedDeviceInfo>
                    <DeviceListIdentifier>urn:uuid:31949239-a1f9-etc-etc-etc</DeviceListIdentifier>
                    <DeviceList>
                        <CertificateThumbprint>2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlW-etc-etc-etc</CertificateThumbprint>
                    </DeviceList>
                </AuthorizedDeviceInfo>
                <KeyIdList>
                    <TypedKeyId>
                        <KeyType>MDIK</KeyType>
                        <KeyId>urn:uuid:154727b3-890c-etc-etc-etc</KeyId>
                    </TypedKeyId>
                    <TypedKeyId>
                        <KeyType>MDAK</KeyType>
                        <KeyId>urn:uuid:682c2ff0-9b1d-etc-etc-etc</KeyId>
                    </TypedKeyId>
                </KeyIdList>
            </KDMRequiredExtensions>
        </RequiredExtensions>
        <NonCriticalExtensions />
    </AuthenticatedPublic>
    <AuthenticatedPrivate Id="ID_AuthenticatedPrivate">
        <enc:EncryptedKey xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                ...(keys hidded for brevity)
                ....(below some of the keys that i need to decrypt)
            <enc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
            <enc:CipherData>
                <enc:CipherValue>lwYdkG5Q5wfW/S7UzZDtnJMcAng3w3ketzkh68y1BeX+okNEj48b5rSWUC/4mNhT
N2QsHxOCkvKDavIGGSAP23tdp0VtdeHTNAszcgK4Xzc8VHGUEiswONCOxTzNWuwj
...etc etc
zfHceeHN50b8vzM/Rt/jTUq54eC3nE+lP3eTXbLj/YvpPo8H45Sti9YP9WZixGHz
Uvf6Go31+3JwsXXIUl3O+w==</enc:CipherValue>
            </enc:CipherData>
        </enc:EncryptedKey>
        <enc:EncryptedKey xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <enc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
            <enc:CipherData>
                <enc:CipherValue>TvC1LCspgTsXqM1b8ClPCtAkAdXXzxe+Av7LMxYtUaqUbd8HeBuaS1cx3WwoVRDr
TWcrBEnv24GbIB5ygcMFW3DlGsXfmWJGnRNx/6xT/U15RQPgoD9AP4WFEHxthzP0
...etc etc
1ajG5lDjEu4TqjdL7DPGNu9HfI9boerJ5FUFQ/fMdD4xbDHdc4DgIQdTUgLFGHJz
RwOyfOAcSNoO/fpAkMXoEw==</enc:CipherValue>
            </enc:CipherData>
        </enc:EncryptedKey>
    </AuthenticatedPrivate>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#ID_AuthenticatedPublic">
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <ds:DigestValue>KJ37JaHCdMo5dq3TmIaxF+A+lpuoVG-etc-etc-etc</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
            <ds:Reference URI="#ID_AuthenticatedPrivate">
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <ds:DigestValue>rcIAaHZoc80XqB70S2oZEp6IziDrVgwt-etc-etc-etc</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>hcOaWg8mzwc61XkyqXxy6+cuuGtrsDjTVzFeSv4ZAs6INQBTYChGiHD00lE8ud02
uG/bbjcqHiMVAFdhZIjw1xIs0FrAh3EdO7eJtiyGl1CpK9z5X9VXizkkhf4wWAZS
....etc etc
0i9iV4sMJlZn4j9glWiTgA==</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                    <ds:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=4py0tKtJ07bHLNbK-etc-etc-etc,OU=...,O=...,CN=...</ds:X509IssuerName>
                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>167201700</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIEZDCCA0ygAwIBAgIECfdLpDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBzMRIwEAYDVQQDEwku
VmltcDE2MDQxEzARBgNVBAoTCi5EQy5DQS5SdVMxITAfBgNVBAsTGC5DbGlwc3Rl
ci5GQk1TLkRDLkNBLlJ1UzElMCMGA1UELhMcNHB5MHRLdEowN2JITE5iS2VwdTRG

-etc-etc-etc
/g07WLzKPQmLxR8I/8GhdyI3Nez+16rJPKMJ3eUV7qLuvA1B2VQ93jBzC4fVvzfI
xFYzYV2RO+VquC/dcgPHKLZPhR1Rp4zP74lGAPIloQa1kpVzjoGypK7QDWLFg+IG
XBtw1dtscIywnqTxYXaxXwic9OlQ2mcmMS7sh2ke2xB9CLYD9JmjPaV71A4J2Y2Y
eF6WeFKIzkKp0fJffqDbFFvKfap3K9e000K/Yno5fFurWW/fagdGEHAXB0zHCj7k
d14u2vegqToKdMsybcA5RngZ7YWYQZKJ
</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                    <ds:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=wiwAlHjwPoipV-etc-etc-etc,OU=....,O=....,CN=...</ds:X509IssuerName>
                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>9714</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIELDCCAxSgAwIBAgICJfIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwajESMBAGA1UEAxMJLkNs
aXBzdGVyMRMwEQYDVQQKEwouREMuQ0EuUnVTMRgwFgYDVQQLEw8uRkJNUy5EQy5D
QS5SdVMxJTAjBgNVBC4THHdpd0FsSGp3UG9pcFY1d3ZEd1pZMFhUYWlNTT0wHhcN
-etc-etc-etc
fiZ3Ljj0uayRAaJtOpflj8RYgWgf2oQvA3vIdc35J2WCea9xm+MLBjycJeaHqgcb
h1hh4qWtaINElm2sdf1p8/feBU0vBV/4ey0TR86tF0FhuVBCg4v9HqrFMY+m4/xJ
wyMCysIxr7ZgszAMOgarYD6JfhNGWm+1VAyI7lR/VspPj6FV0hVOwCb9QZHA/c1Z
5vMeW+Wx3C+1q4HBYHm+ryc7lTt045w7HilTig07g0K6DMaf8G3V5kxZpOQcVWn3
iNFT6Fzg+bE9YD2FdhnVOQ==
</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                    <ds:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=JknMF1MuF3k1Jg-etc-etc-etc=,OU=...,O=...,CN=...</ds:X509IssuerName>
                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>9712</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIEGjCCAwKgAwIBAgICJfAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwYTEOMAwGA1UEAxMFLkZC
TVMxEzARBgNVBAoTCi5EQy5DQS5SdVMxEzARBgNVBAsTCi5EQy5DQS5SdVMxJTAj
BgNVBC4THEprbk1GMU11RjNrMUpnL2JFZm1uWjVpNnlmcz0wHhcNMTUxMDAxMDAw
-etc-etc-etc
+mMkPdu2GuXJj4BBQY0ayoixrSyHg3stATcdeEbU1WESEsmztT8coXMLrd3/W0I6
ahe/dQyOSnZtv8RBL/Zb3Mnih+BQGSbiKlpWNoev71/r5JxA4/grffAfeFjnWy8E
zhAKe9wGx+wR+yQhSBUTHtGE/cA9NfOvOnRvO3BEXsfcJASFXITayaZ7MxP3Mgl/
4RnNxmgKFVY62LLZRo+DmXHhnilVBxrk1YEtBq/mb9R7SYtI5AmfL+B0TUJWGQ==
</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                    <ds:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=JknMF1MuF3k1Jg-etc-etc-etc,OU=...,O=....,CN=....</ds:X509IssuerName>
                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>9711</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIEETCCAvmgAwIBAgICJe8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwYTEOMAwGA1UEAxMFLkZC
TVMxEzARBgNVBAoTCi5EQy5DQS5SdVMxEzARBgNVBAsTCi5EQy5DQS5SdVMxJTAj
BgNVBC4THEprbk1GMU11RjNrMUpnL2JFZm1uWjVpNnlmcz0wHhcNMTUxMDAxMDAw
-etc-etc-etc
iFwmmsU6j0BosEVv/NcdmyoZ68rY0xrjSiCLY7lreHec58ZFXOxNKQsfNJGriyrg
30nMPjp/tgaHK6RZ+XL8sRX9NY+ySBeS/uQtCeH5CtCavIwPrurv5BUbzNmIB5FK
m4wvtXmfVcxTnL4lYHvyhqieDsm+Uwv7Fwt03ygqXeW5IPCs7nqcLwYzhm/7Mn5d
3YBiLH4B0+W2Mq5px0Hrm/2pOVEXv67mbSgdGsHnAYu/f0xN2A==
</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
</DCinemaSecurityMessage>
```

Comment: I guess, you he a document that follows[XML Encryption Syntax and Processing](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core1/). The contents of `CipherValue` depends on the algorithm. Please add to question the contents of the whole `EncryptedData`. For privacy you can crop the data in the elements, but we need to see the attributes that specify details of the encryption.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i have edited my question.